# Slow performance after wubi install of Ubuntu 14 with XP

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, performance

I had an old XP PC that didn't seem like a good candidate for partitioning - various unmovable files and files that couldn't be defragmented. Pentium 4,  2.79 GHz, 1 GB RAM, about 30 GB free before install.

So, I tried wubi. I found a version that installed Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit). Someone said wubi doesn't work with 14, but I have it up.

I made this change to fix an error that prevented it from running "normally":

replaced `ro` with `rw`  in this line:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=AAC884AC1F144321 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

It runs well enough, but seems extremely slow. Did I do the wrong type of install? Is there something I can tweak? I didn't find anything to remove from the startup applications.

I am relatively experienced with MS Windows and DOS (I am comfortable with command-line), but not Linux.

---

Edited to add:

I read that lubuntu and xbuntu current versions won't work with wubi. If that's not true, please direct me!

---

UPDATE:

Maybe partitioning is the way (after another attempt at defragging) -- what's best to use?

Answer (score 2):

Due to your system specs you listed: Pentium 4, 2.79 GHz, 1 GB RAM, I would highly recommend you install either [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (a personal favourite of mine) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) instead of standard Ubuntu. Both variants are lighter on system resources than standard and thus should run better on your hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I researched that and I saw a lot of comments about wubi not working with the current version. I don't think I can partition the drive and I want it on the hard drive.  Should I use an older version?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you cannot partition the hard drive? If you **can** partition and install Lubuntu though, I'm sure it would run great.

Comment: The defrag analysis shows unusable areas scattered across the drive. Seems scary.

Comment: Oh, that is concerning. Sounds like you have some bad sectors. You can try to recover the bad sectors then check the defrag again. [Windows XP Guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/locate-recover-bad-sectors-recovery-console.htm)

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks. From the graphical information on the previous defrag, there's a large expanse of empty space, but there is data on both sides.

Comment: You're welcome. Hmmm, that's interesting. How big is the hard drive? Is the data on either side of the empty space Windows data? Is there any space after the data to the right of the empty space?

Comment: About 30 GB free, but there are files on the right. The largest empty space is about two thirds to the right, with that data after it.

Comment: Okay. Do you want to keep Windows XP? Sounds like you may have enough space if you just format the whole drive.

Comment: Not an option now. I could try another pc if I can't clean up the drive. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use Wubi to install Xubuntu 12 and it runs faster. I haven't seen wubi for 14. So far, this seems ok.